# Laravel Api returns Html instead of json

Tags: laravel, api, cpanel

Hello there my website is on cpanel and when i make an api call it returns contnet-type html instead of json note that it worked perfectly on my localhost but for some reason it isn't working 
Code

```
public function fetch_companies()
{
    //getting company that is linked to coupon
    $companies_id = Coupons::where('company_id' , '!=', 'null')->pluck('company_id');
    $companies = Companies::whereIn('id' , $companies_id)->get();

    return response()->json($companies);
}
```

i tried setting the headers to json like this

```
    return response()->json($companies)->withHeaders([
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ]);
```

but it didn't work

here is the link to my website you may test it using postman 
http://coupon-app.epizy.com/company/api/fetch

just to put you in the picture the code currently running this page is this

```
public function fetch_companies()

    {
        //getting company that is linked to coupon
        $companies_id = Coupons::where('company_id' , '!=', 'null')->pluck('company_id');
        $companies = Companies::whereIn('id' , $companies_id)->get();

        return response()->json($companies)->withHeaders([
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ]);
    }
```

if you need any information please comment and Thanks in Advance

Comment: It looks like that link is returning json `[{"id":5,"name":"Dummy data","company_logo":"\/public\/company\/logo\/1588020544.jpg","created_at":"2020-04-27T20:48:24.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-04-27T20:49:04.000000Z"}]`

Comment: Well... that was on browser. On postman returns html, but you can read the message "This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support". I think you can't use postman to request it https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3344

Comment: Are you sure that is the code that is executed when entering that api. Something like this never happened to me with laravel and postman

Comment: yeah this is the problem on browser it gives json but on postman or a real api request it gives html i searched this problem and read that i should put in the headers the content type i did that but nothing changed i think this might be a problem in the host itself but i have no idea how to connect the host with the problem or i might be wrong about the host . 
the main problem is that the content type is set to json but returns html please assist me if you have experienced such thing before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i found out that the cause of this problem was my server provider as you can find here 
https://infinityfree.net/support/javascript-error-using-api-or-mobile-android-app/
it is a security "feature" although it is not a feature that blocks any request that doesn't accept cookies and run javascript

Answer (score 0):

Change **Accept** & **Content-Type** to *Application/json* on the header